# Loading Dictionary into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to load a python dictionary into a Dataframe.

The structure of the dictionary is unusual, as follows:

```
a = {('a','b','c'): [0.2,0.3],('a','b','e'): [0.25,0.35]}
```

Before I converted to Python 3, the following code used to work

```
b = DataFrame(a.items(),columns=['Systems','stats'])
```

Now, with Python 3.5, I get the error message:

**Error:**

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Use `b = DataFrame(a)`

Comment: @CodeIt - I got `TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`, but in python 3.7

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need convert it to list, or upgrade to last version of pandas `0.25`, then not necessary:

```
a = {('a','b','c'): [0.2,0.3],('a','b','e'): [0.25,0.35]}

print (list(a.items()))
[(('a', 'b', 'c'), [0.2, 0.3]), (('a', 'b', 'e'), [0.25, 0.35])]

b = pd.DataFrame(list(a.items()),columns=['Systems','stats'])
print (b)
     Systems         stats
0  (a, b, c)    [0.2, 0.3]
1  (a, b, e)  [0.25, 0.35]
```